# PHP - Regex Remove anything that is not alphanumeric by keeping some exception

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove anything that is not alphanumeric regardless of lowercase or uppercase and replace with ' '. But some exceptions are there.

exceptions are

> '.!?

But allowing single quote is a headache and I already searched a lot in Stack-overflow didn't find any answer for my requirement.

> $text = preg_replace( '/[^\da-z !\' ?.]/i', ' ', $text );

I tried the above regex but it's replacing single quotes also. But i need to keep that and replace all other non alpha-numeral characters with empty space. Can somebody help me with this?

For eg:

```
$string_input = "So one of the secrets of producing link-worthy! * content is to write quality content that’s share-worthy!"

$string_output = "So one of the secrets of producing link worthy! content is to write quality content that’s share-worthy!"
```

Comment: post your input string and expected result

Comment: Updated, Sorry :)

Comment: Your single quotes `’` are not the single quotes `'` you specify, thats why they get replaced

Comment: Not sure `’` is alphanumerical, you have to add it to the exceptions too

Comment: @PhilippMaurer yeah, now only I noticed it. Sorry for wasting the time bro.. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: i modifier is used, So no issue with capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NOT-pattern in regex:

```
<?php 
echo implode(' ', preg_split('#[^a-z0-9\.\?\'!]#i', $input));
```

You cannot use preg_replace in a simple way to replace all at once. But you can explode on the regex and implode them with a space.

Explaining the regex:

# are delimiter

[] Makes a group

^ all within the group are NOT matched (inverter)

a-z Do not match characters a to z

0-9 Match character 0 to 9

Other characters are escaped.

i flag to make match case insensitive.

Comment: It is also possible with the preg_replace. Did a wrong test: `preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\.\?\'\!]#i', ' ', $input);`